# Can't get AngularJS files to talk to each other

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is most certainly a simple fix for you AngularJS gurus out there. To put it simply, I have taken the angular-seed project down and fine tuned the 'app' folder to my desired file structure. I'm unable to get the root route to show the 'message' specified in the dashboardController scope and called in the dashboard.html view.

Here is the folder structure:

`app
│   index.html
│   app.js

│
└───dashboard
│   │   dashboard.js
│   │   dashboard.html`

Nonetheless I have troubleshooted this for quite some time now and cannot figure out the solution. I have tried taking the boilerplate and running it and it seemed to work. Am I missing something?

Here is the code within each file:

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  </head>
  <body>


    <div ng-view></div>


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="dashboard/dashboard.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

***app.js***

```
  let app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'dashboard/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'dashboardController'
  });
});
```

***dashboard/dashboard.js***

```
angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('dashboardController', function($scope) {
        // create a message to display in our view
        $scope.message = 'Dashboard';
    });
```

***dashboard/dashboard.html***

```
<h1>{{message}}</h1>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `templateUrl: './dashboard/dashboard.html',` ?

Comment: I tried that as well it doesn't seem to be working :/

Comment: Dashboard.js does not have app variable defined. It should be angular.module('app', []).controller('dashboardController', function($scope) {
        // create a message to display in our view
        $scope.message = 'Dashboard';
    });

Comment: @bamittal Tried that code but still can't get that view to render at the root.